# how to place Mat-Card Mat-card-action at bottom of card when we are creating cards dynamically

Tags: css, angular-material, angular5, mat-card

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 home-content" *ngFor="let s of abc">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{s.header}}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>
            <p> {{s.Desc}} </p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="primary">Submit</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 home-content" *ngFor="let s of abc">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{s.header}}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>
            <p> {{s.Desc}} </p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="primary">Submit</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

---

Comment: i am using bootstrap and flex

Comment: When I am dynamically generating the mat-card the content length will vary and that is causing alighnment issues with button . I want button to be at bottom all the time

Answer (score 32):

Add in stylesheet:

```
.mat-card{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mat-card-header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.mat-card-content{
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

font: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11094

Comment: Way to go! This should be the accepter answer!

Answer (score 3):

Solutions if you are using

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>title</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>subtitle</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
  
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>Ok</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

- add a class to the mat-card  .card-internals { min-height: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between; display: flex; flex-direction:
  column; }

i you rather want a spacing like this

```
header
content

action
```

set

```
display: flex; justify-content: start; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap;
```

on mat card and `margin: auto 0 0;` on the mat
card actions

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap you can also do it like this:

```
<mat-card class="h-100">
    ...
    </mat-card-content>
    <div class="flex-fill"></div>
    <mat-card-actions>
    ...
</mat-card>
```

Where flex-fill uses the following css:

```
.flex-fill {
    flex: 1 1 auto !important;
}
```

and h-100:

```
.h-100 {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```